# How to perform Sub Aggregation using NEST?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, dsl

I am trying to perform group documents by certain criteria with a bucket aggregation and perform a sum aggregation for each bucket.

Below is my attempt

```
ISearchResponse<PaymentReportModel> paymentSearchResponse =
                ConnectionToES.EsClient()
                .Search<PaymentReportModel>
                (s => s
                    .Index("payments")                    
                    .Query(q => q.MatchAll() )

                     .Aggregations(a => a

                     .Terms("paymentstatus_types", ts => ts
                        .Field(o => o.paymentstatus)
                            .Aggregations(aa => aa
                                .Sum("sumreceiptamount", sa => sa
                                    .Field(o => o.totalreceiptamount)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    );

var paymentRecords = paymentSearchResponse.Documents ; // Count = 0
```

I am getting Zero(0) count where as there are 356 documents in payments Index.

My DTO is as under

```
public class PaymentReportModel
{
    public string paymentid { get; set; }
    public float? totalreceiptamount { get; set; }        
    public string paymentstatus { get; set; }       
}
```

An equivalent DSL yields

```
"aggregations" : {
    "paymentstatus_types" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "ReceivedByCollector",
          "doc_count" : 36,
          "sumreceiptamount" : {
            "value" : 56914.14031982422
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "CollectionAcknowledged",
          "doc_count" : 17,
          "sumreceiptamount" : {
            "value" : 6802.75
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "PayInSlipCreated",
          "doc_count" : 10,
          "sumreceiptamount" : {
            "value" : 4183.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "CollectionSuccess",
          "doc_count" : 5,
          "sumreceiptamount" : {
            "value" : 27.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What is the mistake that I am making?

Comment: Sure will help you out,I was busy with my tasks and tonight I will check and I wil llet you know by tomorrow morning

Answer (score 0):

So, based on your query you will not get documents because you are using aggregations.That's for sure, still if you want documents then you remove size:0.Then you will get aggregated result as well as documents of size 10.

Comment: Means , i don't understand. where I am using size(0)? Please let me know if I'm disconnect anywhere

Comment: Are you able get documents from the above mentioned query?