# How to make Filter Aggregation inside Bucket Aggregation?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, dsl

I have the below requirement. I have some records which looks as under (as an example)

```
agreementid = 1, lastdispositioncode = PTP , feedbackdate = 30/11/2020 
agreementid = 1, lastdispositioncode = PTP  , feedbackdate = 29/11/2020
agreementid = 1, lastdispositioncode = BPTP , feedbackdate = 21/11/2020
agreementid = 2, lastdispositioncode = BPTP  , feedbackdate = 29/11/2020
agreementid = 2, lastdispositioncode = BPTP , feedbackdate = 11/11/2020
agreementid = 3, lastdispositioncode = SBPTP  , feedbackdate = 24/11/2020
```

Here , first we have to

- first group on agreementid,
- then sort on feedbackdate to get the latest record
- and after that have to count the number of lastdispositioncode.

The above data will give the below result

```
ptp = 1 (since latest record of PTP is on 30/11/2020 for AggrementID = 1)
bptp = 3 (since 

                for AggrementID = 1, latest record of BPTP is on 21/11/2020
                for AggrementID = 2, latest record of BPTP is on 29/11/2020
                for AggrementID = 3, latest record of SBPTP is on 24/11/2020)
```

I have attempted the below program but the query is failing.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ptpDispositionCodes = new TermsQuery
        {
            IsVerbatim = true,
            Field = "lastdispositioncode",
            Terms = new string[] { "PTP" },
        };

        var bptpDispositionCodes = new TermsQuery
        {
            IsVerbatim = true,
            Field = "lastdispositioncode",
            Terms = new string[] { "BPTP","SBPTP" },
        };
        
        ISearchResponse<TestReportModel> searchResponse =
            ConnectionToES.EsClient()
            .Search<TestReportModel>
            (s => s
                .Index("feedbackdata")
                .From(0)
                .Size(50000)
                .Query(q =>q.MatchAll())
                .Aggregations(a => a
                    .Terms("Agreement_ID", t => t
                        .Field(f => f.agreementid.Suffix("keyword"))
                        .Aggregations(aa => aa
                            .TopHits("latest_feedbackdate_sort", th => th.Sort(so => so.Descending(f => f.feedbackdate))
                            
                                .Size(1) //get the latest record 
                            )

                        )
                        .Aggregations(fa => fa

                            .Filter("ptp_aggs", f => f.Filter(fd => ptpDispositionCodes))
                            .Filter("bptp_aggs", f => f.Filter(fd => bptpDispositionCodes))                         
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
        
        var ptpDocCount = ((Nest.SingleBucketAggregate)trailSearchResponse.Aggregations["ptp_aggs"]).DocCount;
        var bptpDocCount = ((Nest.SingleBucketAggregate)trailSearchResponse.Aggregations["bptp_aggs"]).DocCount;
    }
}
```

**DTO**

```
public class TestReportModel
{
    public string agreementid { get; set; }
    public string trailstatus { get; set; }        
    public string lastdispositioncode { get; set; }        
}

public class TestOutputAPIModel
{
    public List<TestModel> TestModelDetail { get; set; }    
}

public class TestModel
{   
    public string TrailStatus { get; set; }
    public int NoOfAccounts { get; set; }
    
}
```

Here is what the response I have received so far

[image]

**As can be figured out that there are two problems**

a) Aggregation on "agreementID" is happening only for the first 10 records (but there are many unique AgreementID's in the system say more than 5/6 lacs)

b) ptp_aggs / bptp_aggs are coming as zero where as there are matching Lastdispositioncodes for those.

What can I try next?

**Edit**

This is the raw query generated which I obtained from DebugInformation

**ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes**

```
{"aggs":{"Agreement_ID":{"aggs":{"ptp_aggs":{"filter":{"terms":{"lastdispositioncode":["ptp"]}}},"bptp_aggs":{"filter":{"terms":{"lastdispositioncode":["bptp"]}}},"paid_aggs":{"filter":{"terms":{"lastdispositioncode":["clmpd","dib","exceemi","odp","partpaid","pr"]}}}},"terms":{"field":"agreementid.keyword"}}},"from":0,"query":{"match_all":{}},"size":50000}
```

**ApiCall.ResponseBodyInBytes**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "sterms#Agreement_ID" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 658,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "2233585285",
          "doc_count" : 513,
          "filter#bptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "filter#paid_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "filter#ptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 513
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "ABCD123456",
          "doc_count" : 95,
          "filter#bptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 8
          },
          "filter#paid_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "filter#ptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 87
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "8728441356",
          "doc_count" : 53,
          "filter#bptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "filter#paid_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 53
          },
          "filter#ptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "5385541121",
          "doc_count" : 39,
          "filter#bptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "filter#paid_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "filter#ptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 39
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "VEH001001",
          "doc_count" : 30,
          "filter#bptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "filter#paid_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "filter#ptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "2671278479",
          "doc_count" : 29,
          "filter#bptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "filter#paid_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 29
          },
          "filter#ptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "4937845646",
          "doc_count" : 27,
          "filter#bptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "filter#paid_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "filter#ptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "4472873928",
          "doc_count" : 25,
          "filter#bptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "filter#paid_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "filter#ptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "LD1736377086",
          "doc_count" : 24,
          "filter#bptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "filter#paid_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "filter#ptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "5548762365",
          "doc_count" : 23,
          "filter#bptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "filter#paid_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 23
          },
          "filter#ptp_aggs" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          }
        }
      ]
```

Comment: Can you please share here the exact failure and also, the query that is being formed at the `NEST` client? You can get that information from the `DebugInformation` property of the search response.

Comment: @Sai Gummaluri , i have updated the question. I am facing two problems

a) Aggregation on "agreementID" is happening only for the first 10 resords (but there are many unique AgreementID's)

b) ptp_aggs / bptp_aggs are coming as zero where as there are matching Lastdispositioncodes for those.

Comment: Can you dump the full ES query please?

Comment: @All, I have updated the question with the Raw Query generated from DebugInformation property of the search response

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar - The update you made looks like a part of the response. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @SaiGummaluri:  I have provided both ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes  and ApiCall.ResponseBodyInBytes

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar can you also share the mapping of your index?